# Реализация отправки уведомлений в личном кабинете пользователя в web-приложении на Java

Tags: java, java-ee

Создаю приложение на Java, в котором должен быть реализован личный кабинет с уведомлениями. Конкретно: есть работник и босс. Работник нажимает на кнопку "Согласовать у босса", после чего боссу приходит в личный кабинет сообщение с просьбой согласовать или отклонить. Босс нажимает желаемую кнопку, после чего работнику приходит уведомление о действиях босса. Что-то вроде упрощенной внутренней почты. Есть вариант хранить всю историю действий в БД (их не должно быть много), и при каждом входе пользователя выгружать ее оттуда, анализировать, какое прочтено, какое нет и т.д., но возможно есть вариант более простой или подходящий? Какая-нибудь особенная технология или библиотека.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим?

Comment: Сталкивался с подобными задачами. Если есть уверенность в том, что функционал будет простым и в дальнейшем не придётся его развивать в нечто большее - то делайте просто и топорно, всё храните в БД, уведомления обычно отправляются по почте. А для обеспечения полноценного сложного документооборота лучше подыскать готовое решение...

Comment: Что имеете в виду под готовыми решениями? На чем они могут быть основаны? В какую сторону копать?))

Comment: Под готовыми решениями я подразумевал Системы электронного документооборота (СЭД). Поисковик выдаст много информации по ним. Например, Alfresco Community Edition - бесплатное решение. Хочу обратить внимание на то, что внедрение готовых решений - это обычно задача не программирования, а внедрения, поэтому будьте готовы к тому, что придётся заниматься непрофильными задачами.